# SMTP: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Error458 block

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

I am building a C# .NET system and have my webmail Mail Client Manual Settings as below:

```
Username: noreply@domain.com
Password: password123
Incoming Server: mail.domain.com (IMAP Port: 993, POP3 Port: 995)
Outgoing Server: mail.domain.com (SMTP Port: 465)
```

My system is trying to send out email using the following settings:

Method 1: In controller method

```
MailDefinition md = new MailDefinition();
md.From = "noreply@domain.com";
md.IsBodyHtml = true;
md.Subject = "subject";

MailMessage mm = md.CreateMailMessage("user1@gmail.com", null, "Some Text", new System.Web.UI.Control());
mm.From = new MailAddress("noreply@domain.com", "System Name");

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("noreply@domain.com", "password123");
smtp.Host = "mail.domain.com";
smtp.Port = 465; //tried for 25, 587
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Timeout = 40000;
smtp.Send(mm);
```

Method 2: In web.config

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="noreply@domain.com">
          <network host="mail.domain.com" port="465" userName="noreply@domain.com" password="password123" defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

I have both methods, also tried for different ports: 25, 26, 587 still having errors like The Operation has timed out.

The error messages of different ports are as below:

```
Port 25: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Error458 block
Port 26: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Error458 block
Port 465: The operation has timed out
Port 587: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Error458 block
```

Also I have searched for Error458, it meant for "Unable to queue messages for node", but no solution on how to resolve this error. Could anyone help?

Comment: You should look at the SMTP Server logs to see why the message is being rejected.

Comment: It seems the problem is on the server. You should look at your firewall settings and SMTP settings on the server. If you don't have access to the server, you should contact the SMTP provider or try another SMTP server.

Comment: I have another SMTP with gmail, smtp.gmail.com with port 587, this can work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a problem with your SMTP server. According [RFC1985 - SMTP Service Extension - ETRN]
[1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1985):

> Since the processing of the queues may take an indeterminate amount
> of time, this command should return immediately with a response to
> the client host.  The valid return codes for this command are:
>
> 250 OK, queuing for node  started
> 251 OK, no messages waiting for node 
> 252 OK, pending messages for node  started
> 253 OK,  pending messages for node  started
> **458 Unable to queue messages for node** 
> 459 Node  not allowed: 
> 500 Syntax Error
> 501 Syntax Error in Parameters

> The 250 response code does not indicate that messages will be sent
> to    the system in question, just that the queue has been started and
> some    action will occur.  If the server is capable of supporting it,
> the    251, 252 or 253 response codes should be used to give more
> information to the client side.  In this case, if there are messages
> waiting for the client side node, a check can be performed using
> these responses codes as an indication of when there are no more
> pending messages in the queue for that node.
>
> **The 458 and 459 result codes should be used to give more
> information** back to the client host as to why the action was not
> performed.  If    the syntax of the request is not correct, then the
> 500 and 501 result    codes should be used.